What is the meaning of "partialFill" in JSON return object on Oanda's v20 API?
Simple question really - I have written several entry order routines using Oanda's v20 API and the returned JSON objects on successfully placing the orders show a key/value pair of
partialFill , DEFAULT

What is this? I can't find anything in Oanda's online API documentation that either explains what this means and what the "default" implies in terms of how the order has been effected. Furthermore, what are the alternative options to "default"?

I have received an answer to this query from Oanda's help desk, which I quote below for forum members' information.

The partialFill = DEFAULT value currently serves a limited purpose. It
indicates that partial fill is possible if the order is marked as
Immediate or Cancel (IOC). Beyond that, the value has no additional
functionality at this time.
However, I would like to assure you that we are actively working on
extending this feature. Shortly, we plan to release an update that
will provide specific details on how orders can be partially filled on
the trigger. This only applies when the Order's Time-In-Force is not
FOK. Once it is released, you will be able to find all of the related
information in our developer's guide.

